# Как сверстать элемент полукруга?

Tags: html, css

Собственно нужно сверстать вот такой элемент:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался делать таким способом, но получалось криво:

```css
.view-catalog {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #800;
  clip: rect(0, 750px, 200px, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="view-catalog">

</div>
```

Comment: Или проще вставить картинкой и не заморачиваться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#container {
  background: pink;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.view-catalog {
  left:57%;
  top: 70px;
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
}

.view-catalog:before, .view-catalog:after {
  position: absolute;
  line-height:0;
  content:"";
  font-size:100pt;
  text-indent:30px;
  top: 0;
  width: 180px;
  height:300px;
}

.view-catalog:before {
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 20px 30px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(69deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(69deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  background: radial-gradient(-50px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #fff 20%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(-50px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #fff 20%);
}

.view-catalog:after {
  left: -275px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-69deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;
  transform: rotate(-69deg);
  transform-origin:100% 0;
  border-radius: 150px 150px 30px 20px;
  background: radial-gradient(230px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #fff 20%);
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(230px 250px, 300px 1200px, transparent 20%, #fff 20%);
  line-height:550px;
  content:"";
  font-size:130pt;
  text-indent:-15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="view-catalog"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Поэкспериментировать с кодом времени нет. Но советом помочь могу. Несложно догадаться что эту фигуру можно получить за счет усеченных трех эллипсов (я их кругами изобразил).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если хотите решать задачу математическим способом вам пригодится тригонометрия, а в вашем случае [синус](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0) или косинус.